# What's difficult about moderating this site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

This question is addressed mostly to moderators, hoping you don't mind the question.

- What's difficult about moderating this site?

  - Gives you a lot of trouble?
  - Costs you a lot of time?
  - Impossible to do well?
- What if anything can experienced users do to help?

For example, I'm guessing that "dealing with spam" is *not* one of the main problems (because so far as I know any spam is dealt with quickly by the system and regular users).

Comment: I'm not a moderator so I will only comment but the most difficult thing I've seen is the personal attacks (which I don't think is too stromg a word) that I've seen both Andrei and Yuttadhammo suffer from. I think it's the nature of these forums - even on a Buddhist forum these things happen - we are all just human beings after all. It is very difficult to see though

Comment: I personally don't find it that difficult at all; I'm just not sure I'm suitable for the job, given my position as a teacher and major site contributor as well.

Comment: @yuttadhammo That sounds reassuring: that moderating isn't that difficult. [You did say](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/1464/254), though, "if there were not enough qualified candidates": so I wondered about the job requirements and qualifications. Especially, whether someone other than you could cope as moderator, even if they had much less knowledge than you (and Andrei) of the subject matter and content (i.e. of Buddhism)?

Comment: Idk... To me competency is more about being moderate. Like fair and impartial. Wouldn't be good to have bad moderators.